# Java print certain characters from an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string array that looks like this:

```
[67, +, 12, -, 45]
```

I want to print it out so that it looks like this:

```
67 12 + 45 -
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use to do this.

```
String[] temp = line.split(" ");
            String tmp = line.replaceAll("\\s+","");

            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            {
                if(isInt(temp[i]) == false)
                {
                    expression = temp[i];
                    firstExp = true;
                }
                else if(isInt(temp[i]) == false && firstExp == true && secondExp == false)
                {
                    System.out.print(expression);
                    secondExp = true;
                }
                else if(isInt(temp[i]) == false && firstExp == true && secondExp == true)
                {
                    System.out.print(expression);
                    firstExp = false;
                    secondExp = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(temp[i]);
                }
            }
```

firstExp and secondExp are Booleans that check for the expressions that should appear in the array. isInt() is just a method used to determine if the string is a number. Right now, all this code does is output this:

```
671245
```

Comment: Is there some rule to get to this result `67 12 + 45 -`

Comment: Basically the rule is that it needs to print all the numbers related to the one expression first, then print the expression itself.

Comment: So what about you have an array like: 65, 23, + ,36, -, 45 ? what would be the output?

Comment: @JorgeCampos i think it should ne `65 23 36 + 45 -`

Comment: I'm not sure where I would start helping you, but I can say that your second `else if` will never evaluate to true because it relies on the result of the first `else if` being false. If the first one is false, your second one will be too.

Comment: Do you need to handle invalid arrays, like [67, 45, -, - ]?

Comment: @chinna_82 and just discard the 23 value?

Comment: @Andrew Jones The first else if checks for whether the string is a number or not. If it's not a number, then it should execute the code in the if-statement. The same thing applies with the second else-if.

Comment: @Dave It can be assumed that all the arrays will be valid.

Comment: @JorgeCampos sorry edited...thats what i understand. Please correct if im wrong.

Comment: @Generalkidd Are you familiarized with recursion ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos The output of the array [67, +, 12, -, 45] when modified should be "67 12 + 45 -"

Comment: How about operator precedence?  so [3, +, 4, *, 5] would be:  4 5 * 3 + ?

Comment: @Generalkidd Think about it this way. else if 1's expression is A. The third condition in else if 2 is B. The only way to get to else if 2 is if A evaluates to false. Since else if 2 is A && B, else if 2 will also be false because it is only reachable if A is false. If this doesn't make since, try finding a case where else if 2 evaluates to true after else if 1 fails.

Comment: @Dave In that case, the output "3 4 + 5 *" Basically the operator only applies to the numbers that precede it, so the numbers should be reordered in any way.

Comment: @AndrewJones I updated the first else if statement so that it can reach the second else if statement. However, it appears to still be printing just the numbers and completely skipping the operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String[] expr = new String[]{"67", "+", "45", "-", "12", "*", "5", "/", "78"};
        int current = 0;
        StringBuilder postfix = new StringBuilder();

        // handle first three
        postfix.append(expr[current]).append(" ");
        postfix.append(expr[current+2]).append(" ");
        postfix.append(expr[current+1]).append(" ");
        current += 3;

        // handle rest
        while( current <= expr.length-2 ){
            postfix.append(expr[current+1]).append(" ");
            postfix.append(expr[current]).append(" ");
            current += 2;
        }

        System.out.println(postfix.toString());
    }
```

Outputs:

> 67 45 + 12 - 5 * 78 /

You can run/edit this at:  http://ideone.com/zcdlEq

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are trying to do is converting infix expression to post fix. Some time back I had written the following code:

```
    public class InfixToPostfix {
   private Stack stack;
   private String input;
   private String output = "";
   public InfixToPostfix(String in) {
      input = in;
      int stackSize = input.length();
      stack = new Stack(stackSize);
   }
   public String translate() {
      for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
         char ch = input.charAt(j);
         switch (ch) {
            case '+': 
            case '-':
            hastOperator(ch, 1); 
            break; 
            case '*': 
            case '/':
            hastOperator(ch, 2); 
            break; 
            case '(': 
            stack.push(ch);
            break;
            case ')': 
            hasSuperior(ch); 
            break;
            default: 
            output = output + ch; 
            break;
         }
      }
      while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
         output = output + stack.pop();
      }
      System.out.println(output);
      return output; 
   }
   public void hastOperator(char op, int precedence) {
      while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
         char opTop = stack.pop();
         if (opTop == '(') {
            stack.push(opTop);
            break;
         }
         else {
            int prec2;
            if (opTop == '+' || opTop == '-')
            prec2 = 1;
            else
            prec2 = 2;
            if (prec2 < precedence) { 
               stack.push(opTop);
               break;
            }
            else
            output = output + opTop;
         }
      }
      stack.push(op);
   }
   public void hasSuperior(char ch){ 
      while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
         char chx = stack.pop();
         if (chx == '(') 
         break; 
         else
         output = output + chx; 
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   throws IOException {
      String input = "67 + 12 - 45";
      String output;
      InfixToPostfix theTrans = new InfixToPostfix(input);
      output = theTrans.translate(); 
      System.out.println("Postfix is " + output + '\n');
   }
   class Stack {
      private int maxSize;
      private char[] stackArray;
      private int top;
      public Stack(int max) {
         maxSize = max;
         stackArray = new char[maxSize];
         top = -1;
      }
      public void push(char j) {
         stackArray[++top] = j;
      }
      public char pop() {
         return stackArray[top--];
      }
      public char peek() {
         return stackArray[top];
      }
      public boolean isEmpty() {
         return (top == -1);
     }
    }
    }
```

You may need to modify this program to read from an array, but that is very trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it in one line:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp).replaceAll("[^\\d +*/-]", "").replaceAll("[+*/-]) (\\d+)", "$2 $1"));
```